# TomEE on eclipse, How to call a remote EJB from a JSF Managed bean?

Tags: jsf-2, ejb, jndi, cdi, apache-tomee

I want to have JSF 2.0 page in one instance of TomEE server calling a Remote EJB running under a different TomEE server, (both obviously running on different ports).

This is what I have done in eclipse...

AppEJB - is a EJB project that contains all the ejb code.
AppEJBInterfaces - This project contains all the remote interfaces, the idea is that this jar will be added to the class path of the web application project containing JSF front end.
AppWeb - is the Dynamic Web Application project containing the JSF front end. 
AppEAR - this contains AppEJB.

Following is the ejb in AppEJB

```
@Stateless(name="UserManager")
@LocalBean
public class UserManagerImpl implements UserManager {
    public void createUser(User user) {
    }
}
```

Following is the remote interface in AppEJBInterfaces

```
@Remote
public interface UserManager {
public void createUser(User user);
}
```

This is what I do in the JSF managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserLoginManager implements Serializable{  
@EJB(mappedName="UserManager")
UserManager userManager;
}
```

I have created a server in eclipse and pointed it to the TomEE 1.6 plus installation. I have added the WebApp to the server. When I right click on the server I don't see the option to add the AppEAR project, so the questions I have are

How do I add/deploy the EJB project or the AppEAR to the server (TomEE in eclipse)?
How do I get the JSF managed bean to lookup the remote EJB?
If we assume that I convert the ejbs to local beans How do I specify the jndi names/config?

Answer (score 1):

Actually TomEE implements most part of JavaEE 6 Full Profile (it is not certified but available in TomEE+, for instance JAXWS, JAXRS, JMS, Connector...). @Remote EJB is in webprofile ditribution.

To lookup you can use RemoteInitialContextFactory or TomEE remote EJB injection feature (not portable).

See http://tomee.apache.org/clients.html and http://tomee.apache.org/ejb-refs.html (end of the page)

edit: you can deploy ear or ejbmodule to tomee using  (see tomee.xml). Just drop the binary inside apps folder you'll create in tomee home

Comment: This works, thanks but I am now getting an error, I have updated the question with the stack trace.

Comment: any help with this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157408/how-to-resolve-api-type-java-util-set-is-not-found-with-the-qualifiers-error?